# Android EditText gets stretched on long text

Tags: android, widget, android-edittext

How do I keep it fixed and the one line text being horizontally scrolled?
(instead of the EditText being stretched until the full screen length)

[Link to the stretched EditText screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1311624/Android%20EditText%20-%20Stretched%20on%20long%20text.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a fixed width and force it to stay on a single line like this:

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: How do I decide what is the best width? I would like to use the width of the background image and not "hard code" the length. This way, if a designer gives me a different background with 5 pixels addition, I would not need to change anything in the code.

Comment: Either you must hard code the width, or place the background as an imageview and align the edittext with the imageview. I would personally prefer to hard code the width. Another option that might be suitable, depending on the background, is to use 9-patch scaling to stretch the background in a nice way.